# How to enforce a header file at the forefront?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, header-files

**Motivation:**

I want to enable the memory detection of VC++, which requires that some statements must be at the forefront as follows:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

**Question:**

Suppose I have a header file `forefront.h`, what I want is the following effect:

a.cpp

```
#include <any_other_one.h>
#include <forefront.h> // An compiler error generated here!
```

b.cpp

```
#include <forefront.h> // OK
#include <any_other_one.h>
```

How to implement?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: While it's entirely possible to do that (e.g. by defining a magic macro in one and checking it in the other), can you really not design the headers to behave correctly regardless of inclusion order? Your users will enjoy your code a lot more if it doesn't fight them.

Comment: This might be a case of "How do I do 'X'", when really, the user needs to be taught how to do 'Y' instead. Rather than forcing header include order, use the project settings to force _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC definition for all files.

Comment: It's usually best to set #define's like that in the build command (i.e. in the Makefile or whatever you use on your platform). Then they will be consistently set (or not) in all translation units.

Comment: @moswald, How do you ensure stdlib.h and crtdbg.h are at the forefront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own header file with the following contents:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

Now use the Forced Includes setting in the Advanced section of the project's settings. Any file specified there will be included before all others, in the order specified.

Comment: +1. This is a good solution, although it is platform-specific!

Comment: Both GCC and Clang support `-include filename.h` to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes. However, it is implementation-defined, not standard-defined

Comment: The question was clearly asked about Microsoft Visual C++, so platform-specific answers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're really asking is how to ensure `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` is defined in all compilation units, use the VC++ project system to add that definition. Go to the project properties dialog, and in the C++ Preprocessor section add `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` to the Preprocessor Definitions line.

Comment: Your answer is to another question.

Comment: Fair enough. I also hate it when people think they know more than me and answer the question they want, rather than the question I asked. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most non-intrusive solution I come up with,

put the following at the beginning of `forefront.h`,

```
#if (__LINE__ != 0)
#error ERROR_FORE_FRONT_IS_NOT_THE_FIRST_TO_INCLUDE
#endif
```

you don't need to change `others.h`.

I tested this code with GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: This does not work for me on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with GCC 4.8.1.  The value of `__LINE__` on the line in `forefront.h` is 1 (unless there's a comment before it), but it doesn't matter what the order of headers is, because the value of `__LINE__` is reset for each header file that's included.

Comment: @John, It doesn't work. `__LINE__` only indicates the line numbers of forefront.h, not that of the translation unit including forefront.h. Still +1 because your novel idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this might work:

**other.h**

```
#ifndef OTHER_H_
#define OTHER_H_
...

#endif
```

**forefront.h**

```
#ifdef OTHER_H_
  #error Wrong include order
#endif
```

Comment: It is better not change other headers if we can accomplish by only changing one header.

Comment: Don't you usually use `#ifndef` in headers file to avoid error given by multiple inclusions?